# How to remove a function from an R script?

Tags: r

I made a function `mean()` taking no arguments. Actually I wanted to calculate mean of some numbers:

```
mean <- function() {
    ozonev <- data[1]
    mv <- is.na(ozonev)
    mean(ozonev)
}
```

As there exists a pre-defined function `mean()` in R, this code is going into recursion. Also, I tried to rename the main function but the previous mean still exists. can any body help me with how to remove that mean function made by me so as to recover the actual functionality of `mean()`.

```
> source("solution.R")

> ls()

 [1] "colname" "data"    "firtr"   "fsr"     "last"    "mean"    "meano"  
 [8] "missv"   "rowno"   "x"       "y"
```

`solution.R` is the script and mean is the function. `meano` is the renamed function.

Comment: Start a fresh session of R maybe?

Comment: `mean <- c(); match.fun(mean)`

Answer (score 7):

You should use [`rm`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/rm.html) to remove your `mean` function.

```
rm(mean)
# or, if you have an environment for this
rm(mean, envir = "<your_env>")
```

But you can't remove the `mean` from the `base` package. It's locked for modification.

Answer (score 3):

Try this.

```
mean <- NULL
```

(I don’t know exactly why this works. But this works.)

Answer (score 2):

There’s a very easy way of avoiding the recursion: call `base::mean` explicitly:

```
mean <- function() {
    ozonev <- data[1]
    mv <- is.na(ozonev)
    base::mean(ozonev)
}
```

Alternatively, you can do something like this:

```
old_mean <- mean
mean <- function() {
    ozonev <- data[1]
    mv <- is.na(ozonev)
    old_mean(ozonev)
}
```

This has the advantage that it will call *any* pre-existing `mean` function that may previously have overridden `base::mean`. However, a cleaner approach is usually to [make a function into an S3 generic](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/OO-essentials.html), and creating a generic for a certain class.

You can edit the function inside the R script, or inside your interactive R session by typing the command

```
man <- edit(main)
```

(Note that you need to reassign the result of `edit`, as I’ve done here!)